# Can someone take my Google Play Android Application's exact name and concept?

Tags: android, actionscript-3, google-play, flash-cs6

Hey everyone so I recently uploaded an Android Application to the Google Play Store about a week ago and I look on the market today to see that two different publishers uploaded an application with the same exact name and same exact concept just different graphics. Is there anything that I can do? I don't have my android application Trademarked or anything. But Is that illegal? Can they really use the exact same name and take the exact same concept.

It's like they went to the store saw that my game might be a good idea and take off so they created the exact same thing.

So is there anything I can do?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about legal issues that are not directly related to programming.

Answer (score 3):

The uniqueness of application in Google Play is based on package name, When any user upload APK file, Google Play will check package name, IF package name is different then it's perfectly legal for Google Play. For concept If you have patent or copy rights or TM, you can contact to Google Play to take action on other apps.

Comment: Thank you for the information. Cant believe they cant even change the name they have to usr my exact name. Its horrible.

Comment: Can you please provide me both links (yours and others) so I can check package name

Comment: Of course. Here is my Game:  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=air.bunnyRunner and here is the copy game: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.FunForMobile.jumpybunny

Comment: Package name is different but It's looks copy of your game but your game is uploaded on 21st march and copy game is upload on 20th march, one day before yours. ???  -- you can use following links for complain

Comment: https://support.google.com/legal/troubleshooter/1114905?hl=en  https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/2853570?hl=en

Comment: I uploaded mine a week ago. I updated it this morning for all screen size support. Thats why it says it was released today which sucks. All my apks contain the date of release so i can still prove I uploaded first correct?

Comment: Thank you i will check out the support

Comment: Yes you can prove, google save all data.

Comment: Hello  user2233653, did you find any solution of your problem, Same situation happened with my friend.  can you please give your contact detail

Comment: No nothing ever happened. His copy version went on to get more downloads as well since he is already a known developer. I direct messaged him about it and he was saying that he was working on that game for months and it was also a class project for his students. Which makes no sense because that simple of a game only takes a few hours to code and publish to the market. Seriously.  I know he was lying but you cant do anything really.

Comment: if you want to talk my email is nathanfitchett@hotmail.com

Comment: thank you my friend Pablo Villar will email you

Comment: alright then sounds good